# How to approach probability type of programming challenge?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

You're dealt 17 cards from a 52-card deck.  On average, what is the longest straight flush you will have in your hand?

A straight flush is a set of cards that are consecutive, and also of the same suit.  2 is low, Ace is high, and you cannot wrap around. Do not solve this mathematically — create a program that approximates this.

I'm not able to think about the correct approach for this type of question. Is there any type of algorithm I have to apply?

Comment: This isn't a particularly high-quality question, but it's definitely not too broad to be answered clearly. The OP is needing a pointer to statistical simulation techniques.

Comment: I second that! Seen @chrylis post, there is a way to answer this question clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of what's called a "Monte Carlo" program, after the casino resort. The idea is to just try a random process a whole bunch of times and look at the statistics.

Basically, you should write a program that deals 17 cards from the deck and counts the longest straight flush. Then you call that a lot of times (maybe 10,000 or 100,000) and take the average.

Comment: also the " do not solve this mathematically" hint is kind of a bad one . I mean it is a program sure , but most algorithms are mathematical in nature, just like this answer is  . Just wanted to point that out since they locked answering this .

Comment: @chrylis just noticed something : this way of simulating the problem mostly depends on how random the program is ... say he uses Math.random or Random.nextInt() or w/e , he would just determine the average based on how random the "randomizer program" actualy is .

Comment: @vlatkozelka Of course it always depends on the quality of your RNG, and since quality randomness is a lot more important for issues such as crypto, a substantial amount of effort has gone into making them good.

Comment: @vlatkozelka My rule number 1: Never use `Math.random` as it's nothing but a static interface to `Random.nextDouble`. 2. Start with `Random`, replace with `SecureRandom` to see if it worked, as this is guaranteed to be perfect.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, but you have to choose between security and speed. For simple tasks like in this question, speed is no problem. For advanced simulations, `SecureRandom` could be too slow and the quality of `java.util.Random` insufficient (the latter is more often a problem).